# MySql : issue with GROUP BY and COUNT clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have this table

[image]

I would like to display products(with their type) that have at least two different types.

Here :

[image]

I have tried this :

```
SELECT PRODUCT, TYPE FROM MYTABLE
group by PRODUCT, TYPE
HAVING count(PRODUCT) > 1;
```

but it doesn't give me the result I want.

Comment: Can you create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: here it is : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c032/2

Comment: e.g. `select disitinct x.product, x.type from my_table x join my_table y on y.product = x.product and y.type <> x.type`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is you want to count by a different grouping than you want to display. One way around this is two have the counting in a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product, type
FROM   mytable
WHERE  product IN (SELECT   product
                   FROM     mytable
                   GROUP BY product
                   HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT type) > 1)
```

Comment: Add _Group by product, type_ in the end

Comment: @The or just `distinct, which is simpler :-) (and thanks, btw)